# Apex Launcher Icons Stopped working?

Tags: themes

I'm trying to code a skin for Apex Launcher however seem to have run into an issue.  I've successfully added several images, however I am now trying to add Authenticator and Google Calendar icons.

I've added the string to iconpack.xml and then added them below in appfilter.xml.  I cannot get the Calendar or Authenticator one working.  If I set the Play Store icon to the one im trying to use for Authenticator it shows the icon.  I'm 100% sure I've got the activity correct as I've looked at the activity from Apex Launcher and have Googled it..

Any suggestions?

```
<!-- Authenticator -->
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.authenticator/com.google.android.apps.authenticator.AuthenticatorActivity}" drawable="com_android_auth" />     

<!-- Play Store -->
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity}" drawable="com_android_store" /> 

 <!-- Calendar -->
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity}" drawable="com_android_calendar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For authenticator, I had to use the following:

`com.google.android.apps.authenticator2/com.google.android.apps.authenticator.AuthenticatorActivity`

Note the addition of only a single "2".

I still can't figure out Google Calendar myself.